# nmap - repeatedly scan a port for a syn/ack reply and output to file

Tags: http, tcp, nmap, port-scanning

I need to hit a http server every second for an ack reply once every second repeatedly for various lengths of time, and to output the replies into a textfile with information such as the response time in ms. this is basically to check for latency, but for my purposes i need to do it with a syn/syn-ack.

I've gotten somewhere with

```
nmap -sS 1.1.1.1 -p 80 -o test.txt -v
```

this outputs well on screen, but not into the text file -- how do i get all the output that nmap runs into the file?

also, not sure how to run this every second - does nmap have a flag for repeating? or shall i just put it in a bash script?

Answer (score 1):

This command is probably doing more than you want. Each time you run it, Nmap does the following:

1. Does a reverse-DNS (PTR) lookup of your target
2. Sends a host-discovery probe to make sure the target is "up." If you are root, this is a set of 4 ICMP and TCP probes. If not, it is 2 TCP connect calls.
3. Sends a TCP SYN probe to port 80. If you are running as root, the sequence is SYN, SYN/ACK, RST. Otherwise it is SYN, SYN/ACK, ACK, RST/ACK.

So instead, you can use some helpful flags to reduce this overhead and be more specific with what you are asking for.

```
nmap -n -sn -PS80 1.1.1.1
```

This command will skip the reverse-DNS lookup (`-n`) and use the host discovery phase to find the latency. `-sn` skips the port scan and `-PS80` says to use TCP SYN to port 80 to do host discovery. Whether the TCP handshake is completed depends on whether you have root privilege or not.

```
nmap -n -Pn -p 80 1.1.1.1
```

This command will send the exact same probes as the previous, but will show the output as a port scan, not just a host discovery scan.

To repeat the scan, you'll have to put it in a shell loop. It would be better to use a dedicated tool for this, but I don't know which one would be best. Nmap comes with a tool called [Nping](http://nmap.org/nping/) that can send repeated probes and report the round-trip time, but I can't get it to display it per-packet; it just gives a summary at the end. You may have better luck with [hping](http://wiki.hping.org/).